# .Net Assemblies Decompiler that Convert Assemblies into C# Source Code

Tags: c#

I am well aware that one can use reflector to browse the content inside an assembly, and one can use [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) to convert the content into the c# source code with cs projects. But the source code outputted by `FileDisassembler` may not be able to compile if it has interface with property.

Is the other similar applications that do what `FileDisassembler` does?

Answer (score 1):

I would not trust Reflector's decompiler.

Many times I have seen it just ignore instruction it did not understand, or just optimized certain sequences away, and changing the meaning the process.

The only trusty way is to use IL.

Regarding more tools, look at the [CCI](http://cciast.codeplex.com/). IIRC, they had a C# source emitter at some stage, but it was removed for some reason.

Comment: @leppie, regarding using IL, any tools for that?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: CCI is good (does round trips very well), else you can try Cecil or ildasm/ilasm.

Comment: you might misunderstand my question. I am looking for a decompiler that decompiles a .Net dll/exe into C# projects, which I think CCI doesn't do.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: I understand. I meant to say (IIRC), at some stage it was capable of doing that.  You could always write your own, as the CCI is very well structured. IMO I would not trust Reflector with a 40 foot barge pole.

Answer (score 0):

dotPeek from jetBrains is a good decompiler for c#. http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/NETPEEK/dotPeek+Early+Access+Program